# Best organisation of view controllers

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I am writing an iOS application in Swift 3.
The application receives an array of 5 colors, each color must have its own ViewController. Each time the application starts the ordering of the colors in the array may be different.

When the user initiates the app they will be presented with a start screen. After pressing a start button they will be directed to the ViewController of the first colour in the array. From there they will be able to press forwards and backwards buttons to navigate through the array of colors and back to the start screen if backwards is pressed on the first color.

What is the best way to arrange and link the ViewControllers?
I would preferably like to use a UINavigationController if possible.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this i would do all programatically.  With a UINavigationController you'll have a bar at the top with a "Back" button all the time.  Sure, you can hide that, but a nav controller isn't necessary for this.

Just create your 5 controllers, then based on the index in the array, present your VC.

```
let vc = ClassOfYourVC() //change this to your class name
self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: You could still have the scenes in the storyboard and instantiate the view controllers that way, you just wouldn't use segues

Comment: Correct.  You will create them in storyboard, but present them programmatically.

Comment: Yes it is.  All that my code shows is how to create an instance of the VC and present it.  No matter if the VC is created in code or the IB, you have to create and instance of it.

Comment: But to get it from a storyboard you need to use `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` on the storyboard object, not a simple Initializer